# keep open session for multiple .net applications on same iis

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7

I have two different .net applications. these both are in same IIS server as different apps, even they are responding on different port.

When login on one of these apps I'm getting out from another app and thats not the behavior we need. Somebody knows the way I can keep the session open in both apps?

Comment: My first guess would be that you are using the same session cookie name for both applications. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017144/rename-asp-net-sessionid) may help you change the cookie name for one (or both) applications. Some additional background may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292449/reason-to-rename-asp-net-session-cookie-name).

Comment: I changed the cookie name for both applications, but I still the second app logs me out from the first app wich I have loged in. I've looked for the cookie information with Fiddler and I found out that the _RequestVerificationToken is the same for both applications, maybe changing that name will help.I've been searching for it but cant find answer

Comment: You have to isolate your session data. Try use sql session provider or redis session provider. The way you have described you are using inproc session